# Email Validation Function Loop Not Pushing All Values

Tags: javascript

I have a comma separated string value that I am attempting to split and clean for valid emails. While I have been able to split the string into an array and have a function to validate the array items for email addresses, it appears that it isn't looping through each item and pushing those that are valid to a new array. At the moment I have just have a single value pushed.

Provided is the string:

```
'test@gmail.com, email, nice@test.com'
```

Here are the functions:

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}  

function emailParser(emailString){
    var preFilterEmails = emailString.split(",");
    var postFilterEmails = [];

    for(i = 0; i < preFilterEmails.length; i++){
        console.log(preFilterEmails);
        if(validateEmail(preFilterEmails[i])){
            console.log("Filtered");
            console.log(preFilterEmails[i]);
            postFilterEmails.push(preFilterEmails[i])
        }
    }
    return postFilterEmails;
}
```

Current output:

```
[ 'test@gmail.com', ' email', ' nice@test.com' ]
Filtered
test@gmail.com
[ 'test@gmail.com', ' email', ' nice@test.com' ]
[ 'test@gmail.com', ' email', ' nice@test.com' ]
[ 'test@gmail.com' ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This because of **whitespace after comma**. You can `trim()` after `split()`

```js
function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}  

function emailParser(emailString){
    var preFilterEmails = emailString.split(",").map(x=>x.trim());
    var postFilterEmails = [];

    for(i = 0; i < preFilterEmails.length; i++){
        console.log(preFilterEmails);
        if(validateEmail(preFilterEmails[i])){
            console.log("Filtered");
            console.log(preFilterEmails[i]);
            postFilterEmails.push(preFilterEmails[i])
        }
    }
    return postFilterEmails;
}
console.log(emailParser('test@gmail.com, email, nice@test.com'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the built-in [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) (along with [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`String.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) to remove the extra whitespace):

```js
const re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

const emailString = 'test@gmail.com, email, nice@test.com';

let emails = emailString.split(',')
    .map(s => s.trim())
    .filter(s => re.test(s));

console.log(emails);
```